# instalation problem for 'survminer' package in R

Tags: r, survminer

I can not install the 'survminer' package in R.

I tried many options already described in the stackoverflow, such as:

library(devtools)
install_github('kassambara/survminer')

Comment: Do you have any error message ?

Comment: Dear @Basti, 

Yes, when I install the survminer : 


>       library(survminer)
Loading required package: ggpubr
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggpubr’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 namespace ‘broom’ 0.7.3 is being loaded, but >= 0.7.4 is required
Error: package ‘ggpubr’ could not be loaded

Comment: You could try to reinstall broom to obtain version >=0.74 : `install.packages("broom")`, then you can try to reload survminer `library(survminer)`